# Variety Gridlocks

Tags: crosswords, three-dimensional

Gridlocks is a word puzzle genre invented by my friend sus. Here's how it works:

- You are given 3x3 crosswords to fill in.
- Two of the crossword clues clue 3-letter words that must be entered down the middle column and the middle row, intersecting in the center.
- Two of the crossword clues clue 4-letter words that can be found be found by anagramming the letters in two separate tetrominoes found in the grid.
- **Clues may be presented in any order.**
- A final answer may be extracted by taking the unused letter in each grid in some order.

Sound confusing? Here's an example:

[image]

..and its solution:

[image]

The 3-letter words are SAT and BAR, and the 4-letter words and PRAY and BASS. The extra letter is T.

Without further ado, here are the puzzles!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: LOL at "2016 Presidential candidate ..."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cubelocks:

> The answers are
>  Before - **Ere**
>  Blunder - **Err**
>  Cold Cubes - **Ice**
>  Deceive - **Lie**
>  Expert - **Ace**
>  Garland - **Lei**
>  Net - **Web**
>  Ocean - **Sea**
>  Polite title - **Sir**
>  Prickly husk - **Bur**
>  Regret - **Rue**
>  Teensy - **Wee**
>
>  Adhesive - **Tape**
>  Chess piece - **Pawn**
>  Den - **Lair**
>  Duct - **Tube**
>  Hay unit - **Bale**
>  Kind - **Nice**
>  Legumes - **Peas**
>  Naked - **Bare**
>  Ooze - **Seep**
>  Rip - **Tear**
>  Sat _ book - **Prep**
>  Très - **Bien**
>
>  These give the following faces of the cube
>  [image]
>  or the full cube
>  [image]
>  Reading the extra letters in the order given by the diagram gives the final answer **BEWARE**.

???????:

> The answers are
>  iPod type - **Nano**
>  Spouse - **Wife**
>  Musician Brian - **Eno**
>  One ___ million - **In a**
>
>  Angsty music - **Emo**
>  Pamper, with "on" - **Dote**
>  Company - **Firm**
>  "I think," in texts - **IMO**
>
>  Anger - **Ire**
>  Passion - **Fire**
>  Before, poetically - **Ere**
>  Delight - **Glee**
>
>  Flightless bird - **Emu**
>  Subatomic particle - **Muon**
>  "I love," in Spanish - **Amo**
>  Qualified - **Able**
>
>  Which we can fit into the grids
>  [image]
>  The extra letters **G, O, E, D** give the corner letters for the final gridlocks puzzle. The wordle puzzles can be solved as
>  [image]
>  These new clues have the answers
>  Fine - **Good**
>  Miff - **Rile**
>  Free - **Rid**
>  Lube - **Oil**
>
>  giving the final grid
>  [image]
>  where we can read the final answer **GRIDDLE**, a combination of gridlocks and wordle.

Gridlocks #3:

> The answers are
>  Many mins. - **Hrs**
>  White-tailed eagle - **Ern**
>  "Moonstruck" actress - **Cher**
>  One of 60 billion in a min. - **Nsec**
>
>  Approves - **OKs**
>  Wisecrack - **Joke**
>  Courage, informally - **Guts**
>  Guitar relative, briefly - **Uke**
>
>  Muslim endowment - **Waqf**
>  Wonder - **Awe**
>  2016 Presidential candidate Nuts - **Deez**
>  Sheep - **Ewe**
>
>  Gambit - **Play**
>  Soul, in France - **Ame**
>  Language also known as Pelasla - **Vame**
>  "Little Women" woman - **Amy**
>
>  with the grids
>  [image]
>  The extra letters give the final answer **IBEX**